# Decode JSon File Using PHP in order to get separate key-value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach-loop-container

I've decoded a Json file using php json_decode() function. 
Now I want to separate key-value pairs from Json file. I used several ways but did not become successful.

I tried foreach loop but it did not provide me separate values.

This is My JSON File

`{"branch_db":"food_maemeshaye","line_items":[{"quantity":"1","product_id":"41","price_id":"4","sale_price":"16.99","topping_id":"0"}]}`

Here is the code

```
$JsonFile = $_GET["line_items"];
echo $JsonFile."\n\n";
$array = json_decode($JsonFile, true);
print_r($array);
```

Here is the output

```
Array
(
[branch_db] => food_maemeshaye
[line_items] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[quantity] => 1
[product_id] => 41
[price_id] => 4
[sale_price] => 16.99
[topping_id] => 0
)

)

)
```

How can I separate [branch_db] and [line_items] from this output?

Comment: Errr, like `$branchdb = $array['branch_db']` and `$lineItems = $array['line_items']` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just directly assign the required parameter value to another variable.

```
$arrBranchDB = $array['branch_db']
```

And

```
$arrLineItems = $array['line_items']
```